# How to disable ASLR without getting malaware on PC

Tags: decoding

So theres this program that is enabled ASLR, I just wanted to know how to enable it without getting viruses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really disable it.
You get the Module with GetModuleHandle and make it return nothing with detours.